# Make link not available in child ASP page

Tags: asp.net

I have master page contain multi links . and I have child pages .
How I can make some links not available in child page ?

Answer (score 0):

There may be many ways to do this, but this one is my preferred method to control the visibility of links on child pages. I usually have a `ContentPlaceHolder` for placing specific links and fill the links from the child page on which I need extra links more than that of Master page.

In this way, you can control the links per child pages.
So, Put an empty `ContentPlaceHolder` on master page and fill it the same way you fill the content specific to the page.